# using row from first part of SQL union in second part

Tags: sql, sqlite

To implement a multiple choice quiz I want to select an answer from my answers table (the "correct" answer) and two "incorrect" answers.  Can I do it in one query.  I feel I should be able to but I'm not quite getting it.   Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT correct.answer
FROM (
    SELECT answer
    FROM answers
    ORDER BY random()
    LIMIT 1
) correct
UNION
SELECT answer
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT answer
    FROM answers
    WHERE answer != correct.answer
    ORDER BY random()
    LIMIT 2
);
```

The database engine is SQLite 3 which gives me:

```
Error: no such column: correct.answer
```

I can do it with two separate queries but like I said, one should be possible no?

Comment: maybe I'm missing something, but aren't you then just selecting all the records from answers? I think union will deduplicate anyway (not 100% with sqlite, but that is how it works in MSSQL, Oracle, MYSQL)

Comment: What determines if it is a correct answer?

Comment: @Greg: SQLite does understand the difference between UNION (set-wise union so no duplicates) and UNION ALL (include duplicates).

Comment: In your query to select the 'correct' answer, you're not using any predicates - in fact it looks like you're selecting the 'correct' answer randomly?

Comment: Yes here I am selecting the correct answer randomly.  There will be another piece of SQL that determines the question that goes with this answer and then both the question and the choices will be shown to the user but to keep this question simple, I left all that out.

Comment: Your approach makes not so much sense. You select a random row and `UNION` it with two other randomly choosed rows which are not the same like the first choosed row. In this case: Why not choose three random rows and use the first one as the correct one? You should rethink about what you really want to do. It seems your try for simplfy the problem destroyed it.

Comment: I think you are right in terms of how I should proceed for my project.  But as a person trying to improve his SQL knowledge, the underlying issue still intrigues me.  Can a value from one select in a union be used in another select?  (In standard SQL.  Some DBEs have DECLARE but that is an extension isn't it.

Comment: Yes, I see. Im not sure about this question. I think it is not possible because `UNION` is only for combining the result of two or more `SELECT`s. In your case you try to access the first result set within the second `SELECT` and i think there is no way for that (but im not expert in SQL). For your problem you should use at least two tables named QUESTION and ANSWER with an 1:n relation between them. In the answer table you can use for example a column like 'IsCorrect' to know about which answer is correct. The rest should be trivial.